# Colour of lines in ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, color

How do I change the colour of these lines from black to, let's say, red?

```
ContourPlot3D[25 (x^3 (y + z) + y^3 (x + z) + z^3 (x + y)) + 
50 (x^2 y^2 + x^2 z^2 + y^2 z^2) - 
125 (x^2 y z + y^2 x z + z^2 x y) + 60 x y z - 
4 (x y + x z + y z) == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0]], Mesh -> None, 
ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 2}]
```

Although researching for quite a while, I could not find the answer. Thank you indeed for pointing it out to me.

Comment: `% /. Black -> Red`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ContourPlot3D[
 25 (x^3 (y + z) + y^3 (x + z) + z^3 (x + y)) + 
   50 (x^2 y^2 + x^2 z^2 + y^2 z^2) - 
   125 (x^2 y z + y^2 x z + z^2 x y) + 60 x y z - 
   4 (x y + x z + y z) == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False,
 ContourStyle -> FaceForm@None,
 BoundaryStyle -> Red,
 Mesh -> None,
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's not important but FYI the png format is better for graphics

Comment: are you using [**this**](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5/193). It's very nice!

Comment: Perfect! Thank's for all the help!